# Retrieve product information as JSON with Stencil Utils

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

Using `stencil-utils`, I can retrieve product information for a given product ID. However, I can't find any documentation on how to retrieve the information as a JSON response as opposed to an HTML template.

Right now, I'm using the following code:

```
utils.api.product.getById(
    847,
    {},
    (err, resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
    }
)
```

I'm hoping there's a parameter I can pass in the params object that will return the response as JSON so I can extract just the information I need about the product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `{ params: { debug: "context" } }` will work great on the local environment created using `stencil start`, however once you bundle & upload your theme to a live site, it stops working. The debugging tools `debug: "context"` and `debug: "bar"` are disabled on production.

After reaching out to bigcommerce support, which originally linked me to this SO question, it seems this is their proposed workflow:

You will have to use a dummy handlebars template, include the variables you need, and use the custom handlebars helper provided by bigcommerce, `{{json}}` - which seems to just run `JSON.stringify()` - the helper is defined [here](https://github.com/bigcommerce/paper/blob/master/helpers/json.js).

```
utils.api.product.getById(
    847, { template: 'path/to/template' }, (err, resp) => {
        // Will print the name of the product.
        console.log(resp.product.title);
    });
```

I have had success with `path/to/template` being `custom/template-name` and placing the handlebars template in the `templates/components/custom` folder. I have not tested passing it a template from another source.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you can pass additional parameters by adding a `param` object to the options. With `debug: "context"`, you can retrieve the entire context of the page, and you can then get the product information by accessing `response.product`.

```
utils.api.product.getById(
    847,
    { params: { debug: "context" } },
    (err, resp) => {
        // Will print the name of the product.
        console.log(resp.product.title);
    }
)
```