# BigCommerce Get Product Color Swatch Variation Image via Stencil Utils API (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, bigcommerce

I'm trying to fetch a product's color variation image via Stencil's Utils API and it's close to becoming a nightmare. [And the supposed documentation shows exactly nothing almost...](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/stencil-utils-api-reference)

I finally [managed to get a request done of a product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090421/retrieve-product-information-as-json-with-stencil-utils/35092426#answer-37976026) but those options images are yet to be found... nothing in that returned JSON!

I was trying to do some digging and see what I could find in other utils like this: `utils.api.productAttributes.optionChange(productId, params, callback)` but didn't quite get what to send in those params this time.

Anyone with a bit more knowledge on how to accomplish this? On how to retrieve those product color variation images?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What page are you trying to load them on? Digging around the assets/js/theme/common/product-details.js file and logging the data returned has taught me a lot.

Comment: Yes! That's totally true! I've already solved it! Thanks a lot for answering though! I actually spend all day around that javascript trying to understand every little bit of code and ended up FINALLY understanding the inner workings of utils.hooks and utils.api! :D

Am going to fill in an answer later on for future reference to people.

Comment: @AlexandreRosário Yeah an explanation would be extra helpful. I'm about to go into utils.api land myself but would super appreciate to read over someone else's findings as a guideline.  As a sidenote, I feel like the Stencil framework uses really great technologies but drops the ball completely on documentation.